# Prevent DataGridView selecting a row when sorted if none was previously selected

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview that may or may not have rows selected when the user sorts it by clicking on a column header.  If there are rows selected there isn't a problem, but if there are 0 selected rows then the sort selects a row automatically (the selection is consistant but I'm not wure what the criteria is).  How can I prevent this behavior from happening.

If it's relevant, the DGV is not databound and has full row select enabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Handle the Sorted event of the DataGridView:

```
this.dataGridView1.Sorted += new System.EventHandler(dataGridView1_Sorted);

void dataGridView1_Sorted(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
}
```

Comment: That would also clear existing user selections which I want to be preserved.  There doesn't appear to be an event that fires before the sort is carried out like there is when a form is closed (FormClosing and FormClosed) that I could use to check the state to determine if the selection should be cleared afterwards.

Comment: The CellMouseDown event fires before the sort and can be used to check the selection state. The more likely looking ColumnHeaderClick event fires after the sort and is useless.

Comment: The additional code needed is:

bool selectionsMade = false; private void DataGridView_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) { if ((e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) && (e.RowIndex == -1)) { selectionsMade = (((DataGridView)sender).SelectedRows.Count > 0); } }

Comment: Did the additional handling code you mention solve your issue?

Comment: Yes, combining it with your sorted event did solve the issue.

Comment: Note that this does not prevent the SelectionChanged event from firing.

Comment: You'll also need to set the selectionsMade member any place where you might Sort programmatically.